# How to get FavIcon of the current tab in macos(OSX) Swift

Tags: swift, macos, safari, osx-yosemite

Using this code i am getting current url and tabName but i want Favicon of that current tab opened

```
let safariApplication = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Safari")! as SafariApplication
        self.windows = safariApplication.windows!().reduce([String: SafariWindow](), { (dictionary, object) -> [String: SafariWindow] in
            let window = object as! SafariWindow
            
            let tabName = window.name
            let safariTab = window.tabs?().object(withName: "\(tabName ?? "")")
            let url = (safariTab as AnyObject).URL
            
            urlValue = url ?? ""
            tabName1 = tabName ?? ""
            print(url ?? "")
            print(tabName ?? "")
            var dictionary = dictionary
            dictionary[window.name!] = window

            return dictionary
        })
```

Comment: Which version of Safari do you use? Does a tab have an icon property in the AppleScript Dictionary or in Safari.h?

Comment: Safari version14 and this is the safari.h i am using https://github.com/tingraldi/SwiftScripting/blob/master/Frameworks/SafariScripting/SafariScripting/Safari.h

Comment: Safari 14 on OS X Yosemite?

Comment: yes Safari 14 , in the above github there is no icon property and i am going nowhere with it.

Comment: On OS X 10.10 Yosemite, are you sure? Which version of macOS are you using?